# file manager doesn't display subfolder

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

Using Expresso I want to insert an image from a sub-folder of the upload directory. But the file manager doesn't display the subfolders, even after to synchronize the files. I tried many settings with no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default file manager does not allow for browsing of subdirectories. You would need to use something like Assets ( http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets ).

Comment: Thanks Justin, i didn't know about that. Channel files seems to be a solution too.